# Account not associated

Tags: support, status-completed

### Now fixed, many thanks to our human overlords!

I just created an [account](https://serverfault.com/users/34091/fx) on serverfault.com, using my usual Google credentials. However, it did not auto-associate with all my other SE accounts. So, I suppose something weird is going on. Can someone check it out?

---

It seems to be a bug, because my new account was awarded the Association Bonus. Also, when I click on "My logins" to see which credentials are associated to the account, it displays an empty list:

[image]

Comment: *"member for 2 years, 1 month"*?

Comment: [I didn't get an automatic association when a question got migrated either](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3096/why-was-my-question-considered-not-acceptable-for-server-fault/3097#comment5787_3097). Perhaps related?

Comment: @mmyers yeah, apparently I already had an account a long time ago?

Comment: It's associated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have associated your accounts - enjoy!